# Most efficient way to echo PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have an SQL query which I have recently turned into a prepared statement for security purposes. I have a query which returns many rows, each consisting of many columns. My question is how to echo the results using a while loop. My example I have so far:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers 
                                  WHERE travel_Date >= ?
                                  AND   travel_Date <= ?
                                  ".$searchOption."
                                  LIMIT ? 
                                  OFFSET ?");
$todayDateFrom = $todayDate." 00:00:00";
$todayDateTo = $todayDate." 23:59:59";
$stmt->bind_param("ssii", $todayDateFrom, $todayDateTo, $limit, $offset);
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //echo first name
    //echo surname
    //echo address
    //echo number
    //echo type
    //15 other things i need to print off
}
```

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I have thought about:

```
$stmt->bind_result($firstName, $surname, $address, //etc);
```

But I'm wondering if there's another alternative similar to unprepared statements:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['firstName'];
    echo $row['surname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    //etc
}
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? `$stmt->bind_result` allows you to load everything into nicely named variables and echo them out just the same. I don't understand why your second set of code is considered any better than the first in terms of effort.

Comment: @Polynomial It's not specifically a problem, i'm just looking for an alternative to printing out results similar to the way unprepared statements are done. If there isn't an alternative, i'll end up using $stmt->bind_result()

Comment: Again, I don't quite see what you're getting at. Do a `bind_result()` before your fetch loop and the variables will be automatically updated each time you call `$stmt->fetch()`. What specifically is problematic about this approach? What is the specific benefit of the old style code that you're looking to take advantage of?

Comment: @Polynomial When vinding the results, I see you have to bind all columns. Where as I don't need ALL the columns, I need approx 20 out of the 30 columns in my table. so with the bind_result I have to bind all 30 columns instead of the 20 that i need

Comment: So why fetch the columns that you don't need? Specify the columns you want in your SELECT. That way you don't need to worry about all the extra columns, and your query needs less memory to execute.

Comment: @Polynomial Way to think outside the box. I never thought of that.

Comment: it doesn't sound like a realistic scenario. plain `echo`ing all the fields will create a huge mess. what are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what i'm trying to achieve is to display all customers with all their details. Before preparing my statements I just called the query in a while loop echoed all the results. now that there is sensitive data i need to change the way i display my info if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        echo $row['firstName'];
        echo $row['surname'];
        echo $row['address'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$result_arr = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $record = array();
  $record['firstname'] = $row['firstname']; // if your db column contains firstname column other wise you can also use $row[0];
  $record['name'] = $row[1]; // end so on .......
  $result_arr[] = $record;
}
```

hope this will work for u...